# Minimum power rating of zener diode

Tags: power, diodes, zener

The minimum power rating of a zener diode is defined as the maximum power that can be dissipated through it in a given circuit.

Why do we define it in the opposite way? Minimum power rating should be the minimum power dissipated in the diode.

Can anyone please clarify.

Comment: *Minimum power rating should be the minimum power dissipated in the diode* What if I told you that all Zener diodes have a minimum power rating of 0 W (zero Watt). If you disagree please feel free to prove that my statement is wrong.

Comment: If you take a look at zenner diode characteristic you may found the value of current where voltage most stable. With smaller current you may not get nessessary voltage. So it is not about power dissipation, it is about stability.

Answer (score 1):

The zener must be power rated accordingly so, if the maximum power that can be dissipated through it in a given circuit is \$\boxed{X}\$, the zener diode must, as a minimum, have a power rating of at least \$\boxed{X}\$ at the full working temperature of the local ambient surrounding it. In fact, when taking reliability into account, the minimum should be somewhat greater than \$\boxed{X}\$ (possibly 1.25 times greater). That's called [de-rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derating#:%7E:text=In%20electronics%2C%20derating%20(or%20de,current%20rating%2C%20or%20voltage%20rating.)): -

> **In electronics, derating (or de-rating) is the operation of a device
> at less than its rated maximum capability in order to prolong its
> life. Typical examples include operation below the maximum power
> rating, current rating, or voltage rating.**

See also the de-rating graph in that wiki article: -

[image]

Comment: Ok, so if at max, the power dissipated through the diode can be say 5W then I should take at least a min power rated diode of 5W. But when I put it in the circuit most of the time the power dissipated across it will be less than 5W. But my choice is for a  5W diode, so it won't work correctly?

Comment: Power is voltage x current.

Comment: I wrote it incorrectly. I would request to have a look at the comment if possible.

Comment: If the peak power is 5 watts for anything longer than a tenth of a second then it needs to be rated at 5 watts to prevent it overheating. However, if the average power is less then it is the average that is the value that needs to be considered providing that it is cyclic and the cycle length doesn't get anywhere near (say) 10 milli seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is during the design phase of a circuit.

The diode must have at least the same power rating as the maximum power which will be dissipated in the circuit.

So if you select a suitable zener diode the minimum required power rating is the maximum power in the circuit, so that the diode will not fail during usage.

If you want to create a reliable product, you should assume failure models and select protection devices like a zener diode according to those assumptions. So even if the normal use case would say a 0.5 W zener diode is suitable, your failure case could require a 2 W zener diode.

---

From the comment section:

> Ok, so if at max, the power dissipated through the diode can be say 5W
> then I should take at least a minimum power rated diode of 5W. But
> when I put it in the circuit most of the time the power dissipated
> across it will be less than 5W. But my choice is for a 5W diode, so it
> won't work correctly?

The function (sharp drop off in breakdown region) of a zener diode is not dependent on the power rating of the diode or the power dissipated by the diode. Of course the current working temperature (which depends heavily on the dissipated power) will have an influence on the breakdown voltage and leakage but the basic working principle will still be the same.

You can get a 8 V zener diode with a maximum rating of 0.15 W and one with 1.5 W for example. Both will work equally fine when they only have a dissipation of 10 mW. The 1.5 W one will just be a bit cooler as it is better at getting heat out.

Comment: Ok, so if at max, the power dissipated through the diode can be say 5W then I should take at least a minimum power rated diode of 5W. But when I put it in the circuit most of the time the power dissipated across it will be less than 5W. But my choice is for a 5W diode, so it won't work correctly?

Comment: @YasirSadiq I tried to answer the follow up question in my answer - but this is usually discouraged on this site, it's better to ask a new question if it pops up, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume a part named P in your system consumes DC current 0...100 mA and it needs operating voltage +12 V. But your power supply provides +15 V and the rest of the system needs it. You solve it by inserting 3V/100mA =30 Ohm series resistor which drops the voltage for P to 12 V in case P happens to draw 100 mA. Because it can draw less than 100 mA you insert also a 12V zener diode  in parallel with P. It would draw just as much as is needed to drop the voltage to 12V. For example P draws 10 mA, the zener diode draws 90 mA - that's how it regulates the voltage.

In case P alone draws 100 mA the zener diode takes nothing - it dissipates blank zero watts. If you use a zener diode which is guaranteed to stay alive only if it dissipates 0 watts you cannot at all be sure how it works after dissipating some time 1.2W - that's the dissipation which should happen in the diode when load P draws 0 mA and the diode draws all of the needed 100 mA which should be drawn to drop the voltage from 15 to 12 volts in a 30 Ohm resistor.